# SQL - PHP foreach variable ID outside loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, foreach

I would update the value field of a specific ID that's generated from a `foreach` loop.

```
$sql = "SELECT `user_id`,
     max(case when  `meta_key` = 'link' then `meta_value` end) as link ,
     max(case when  `meta_key` = 'team' then `meta_value` end) as team ,
     max(case when  `meta_key` = 'points' then `meta_value` end ) as points 
     FROM wp_usermeta GROUP BY `user_id` ORDER BY points DESC";

global $wpdb;
$usermeta = $wpdb->get_results($sql) or die(mysql_error());


foreach ($usermeta as $post)
    echo "<li> name:  ". $post->team ."<br/> link: ". $post->link . "<br/> obtain: " .$post->points. " points </li>" ;
```

the output on the page is something like:

> team: manchester link: manunited.co.uk points: 8

A user can vote the team and the team earn 8 points, so i need update like this.

```
update_usermeta( $post->user_id , 'points', $_POST['points'] );
```

the problem is that outside the foreach the variable `$post->user_id` is not recognized but i need the specific id of team to update it.

Thank to all.

Comment: Store it in a temp variable declared before the loop?

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors.  The only reason you need them is if you have a column name that is a reserved word, and using column names that are reserved words is a terrible idea, so that's two bad habits you can avoid at once.

Comment: @AndyLester: <pedant>Quotes are also needed for identifiers that contain ASCII characters other than basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore; or which consist solely of digits.</pedant>

Comment: I'll add those to my list of bad practices to avoid, thus reinforcing the idea that quoting column and table names is a bad smell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to declare:

```
global $post;
```

outside the foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks i solved! i declared it before the loop but wasnt work so i redeclared it after and worked! thanks